# Efficient way to store append rows into dataframe stored in disk.

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am very new to Pandas(Dataframe).

I have approximately 43000 documents in disk, I process each document one by one. While processing I extract entities and keyword from the documents. I store the document id and the entities frequency in a pandas dataframe. There is a high possibility that the count of the total entities may cross a million building the dataframe to a size of 43000*10,00,000. Therefore, I cannot store the entire dataframe in the memory.

I need an efficient way to store a dataframe in the disk and append each row (dic_id and entity freq) one by one to the dataframe.

My dataframe looks like :

```
         India   America   Sam   New York    Las Vegas    Football .............
doc1       3        1       6      1            0             0    ..........
doc2       0        0       0      0            0             2    ..........
```

What I want to achieve:

```
for documents in disk:
    read document  (Example: doc1, doc2....)
    find entities and their frequency (Example: India, America , New York, Las Vegas....)
    insert the entities into a dataframe stored in the disk.
```

Comment: There is a high possibility, your dataframe would be an ideal fit for sparse storage. Explored sparse matrix?

Comment: Thanks John, I am aware of the scipy sparse matrices, but do not possess  much knowledge on appending or deleting rows from sparse matrices. Thought as a starting point dataframe would suffice, also I having a dataframe would be easy for debugging purpose..